# Netbeans build-impl.xml messed up

Tags: java, xml, netbeans

My build-impl.xml file was messed up due to merge conflicts. I fixed the conflicts, but when I try an `ant run`, it throws `Target "-do-jar-delete-manifest" does not exist in the project "PROJ". It is used from target "-do-jar-without-libraries".` This is a Java FX project and we are using Java 8.

I would like to fix this by just creating a new build-impl.xml file. How can I do this in Netbeans? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I deleted `build-impl.xml` and then restarted Netbeans. Netbeans regenerated all the build files, and it was able to run.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem also and probably is because the build-impl.xml is corrupted.

I have created a new glassfish server and then it has worked!

Answer (score 0):

With the same problem, I had to delete both build-impl.xml and build.xml. After restarting NetBeans I could run my project.

Answer (score -1):

In the Projects window, right click the project and select Delete. Do **not** check the checkbox to delete the sources and click the Yes button. Then create the project again: File -> New Project, Category Java, Java Project with Existing Sources.

Alternatively, go back to the working build-imp.xml from your Version Control System.